# "and" is necessary in a sentence with two conjunctions such as "after" and "until"

Tags: conjunctions

I am not sure whether the word "and" needs in the following sentence I created:

> I studied all the time after my mother returned home (and) until my father returned home.

Could anyone give me advice !

Comment: The time between my mother and my father getting home I spent studying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's stilted.  You're describing an interval of time - use from/to or from/until.  After/until is not a normal pairing.

> I studied *from* the time my mother returned home *until* my father returned home.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not needed. Using "and" in the sentence makes it sound incomplete; as if another action was expected. For instance, "I studied all the time after my mother returned home and until my father returned home, I coudn't stop."

Comment: Hard to say. You have a point that the *and* could create a garden path to another independent clause (although not using a comma should help). On the other hand, readers may expect an adverbial of time (*until*) to apply to the mother's return instead of the child's study.

Answer (score 0):

I would write it like this.

> In the time after my mother and until my father returned home I would study.

There is no need to repeat "returned home" twice, I think that is the mistake not the "and".